# Python multiple web pages scraping with same starting url string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read review data data from alexaskillstore.com website using BeautifulSoup. For this, I am specifying the target url as https://www.alexaskillstore.com/Business-Leadership-Series/B078LNGS5T, where the string after Business-Leadership-Series/ keeps changing for all the different skills.

I want to know how can I input a regular expression or similar code to my input url so that I am able to read every link that starts with https://www.alexaskillstore.com/Business-Leadership-Series/.

Comment: in principal the corresponding regular expression would be `r'https://www\.alexaskillstore\.com/Business-Leadership-Series/.*'` or `[A_Z0-9]+` at the end. In order to see how you apply that it would be nice to see some code you already have, containing the basic set-up and a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The web is client-server based, so unless the server is kind enough to map the content for you, you have no way to know which URLs will be responsive and which won't.

You may be able to scrape some index page(s) to find the keys (B078LNGS5T and the like) you need. Once you have them all, actually generating the URLs is a simple matter of string substitution.